# applicationname="/" even though explicitly specified?

Tags: asp.net-membership, profile

when my page config.aspx loads, a profile entry is created in association with the current user - This is working fine.
However, even though I specify explicitly the applicationname="MyTool", the applicationname field is set to '/' in the aspnet_applications table

So I'm guessing that there is another place where I should set the applicationname - so far I have:

```
<add name="SqlProvider" 
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
     connectionStringName="MyToolConnection" 
     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
     enablePasswordReset="true" 
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
     applicationName="/MyTool"              <-- I tried both "MyTool" and "/MyTool"
     requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
     minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
     passwordFormat="Hashed" 
     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
     passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
     passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />


 <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" >
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="MyToolConnection" applicationName="/MyTool" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/MyTool" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>




 <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Application Name=/MyTool;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyTool;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MyToolConnection" connectionString="Application Name=/MyTool;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyTool;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned "profiles" in your question.

Are you also setting the application name in the `<profile>` element of the web.config?

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlServices">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
connectionStringName="SqlServices" applicationName="MyTool" />
</providers>
```